# move semantics 2d vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, move-semantics

I have a question on C++ move semantics in 2D vector (or a vector of vectors). It comes from a problem of dynamic programing. For simplicity, I just take a simplified version as the example.

```
//suppose I need to maintain a 2D vector of int with size 5 for the result. 
vector<vector<int>> result = vector<vector<int>>(5);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  vector<vector<int>> tmp = vector<vector<int>>(5);
  
  //Make some updates on tmp with the help of result 2D vector
  
  /*
    Do something
  */

  //At the end of this iteration, I would like to assign the result by tmp to prepare for next iteration.

  // 1) The first choice is to make a copy assignment, but it might introduce some unnecessary copy
  // result = tmp;

  // or

  // 2) The second choice is to use move semantics, but I not sure if it is correct on a 2D vector. 
  // I am sure it should be OK if both tmp the result are simply vector (1D).
  // result = move(tmp);

}
```

So, is it OK to simply use `result = move(tmp);' for the move semantics of 2D vector?

Comment: In this example, `result` and `tmp` are both about to be destroyed by going out of scope. As such, we can't answer. Give us a real example where we can compare the variable lifespans, at the very least

Comment: `std::move()` works for 2D vector in the same cases as for vector. Your `result = std::move(tmp)` should be fine.

Comment: I'm not sure (your explanation is a bit short), but I think you are getting too hung up on this idea of a "2D vector". Your `tmp` variable is a vector of something. That "something" happens to be another vector, but abstract that away. Vectors are designed so that they can be used without knowing what type they hold. Your `tmp` variable is a vector of something. Done. Back to the world of 1D vectors.

Comment: If you are worried about whether `move` would recurse down to the elements, that doesn't happen. The contents of the `vector` (which is usually a pair of pointers, or a pointer and a length) are transferred to the other `vector`.

Comment: It helps me to just consider "2D vector" as a vector of something, which happens to be a vector of int (by @JaMiT).

Comment: The comment by @jxh shows the reason why I worried about it before. It looks `std::move()` would not touch any element of the underlying array in vector (i.e., it would recursively call the `std::move()` on each element). It simply transfers the pointer of underlying array (and also need to do something on other private members).

Comment: @Jeffrey The name of variable `result` might cause some confusion.  For example, I would return result[0] at the end of this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because result is not '2D' vector, it's simply 1-D vector of vectors.